# Add turtle pos() to a array/matrix/variable

Tags: python, matrix, turtle-graphics

I was wondering it is possible to to have `pos()` (turtle python) to be added to a vector or variable for example if output of `pos()` or a values like [23,12] and you save it as `[23,12]` (Matrix Python) or `n = 23` and `m = 12`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`turtle.pos`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.pos) says

> `turtle.pos()`
>   Return the turtle’s current location (x,y) (as a `Vec2D` vector).

Then going to the [`turtle.Vec2D`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.Vec2D) documentation

> `turtle.Vec2D(x,y)`
>   A two-dimensional vector class, used as a helper class for implementing turtle graphics. May be useful for turtle graphics programs too. **Derived from tuple, so a vector is a tuple!**

So it essentially behaves like a `tuple`. If you want to convert it to something else, you can just do things like

```
a = list(turtle.pos())          # list of values
b = numpy.array(turtle.pos())   # numpy array of values
```

The `Vec2D` class has operations that the other containers do not have, namely affine geometry operations like adding, subtracting, inner (dot) product, vector-scalar multiplication, etc.

Comment: 'a = list(pos())' Doesn't seem to work, as if I want to recall a value again it said a is not defined.

Comment: I'd have to see your code snippet that is causing that issue. You may be in a different function, scope, etc where your variable no longer exists.

Comment: Sure! Updated OP.

Comment: Hmm that code should not produce the error you mentioned, `lista` is still in scope and is certainly defined.

Comment: I have also check manually via typing `lista` into console and still give the same error.

Comment: So when I add print command it return [0,0] which means it doesn't actually make a  vector.

Comment: Nevermind, it was working the whole time. It just because it def you canno't for the function.